# IE7 ul display:none/block problem

Tags: css, list, mootools, internet-explorer-7

I've got a strange problem with IE7.
This is my html:

```
          <div class="nav square">
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#square" class="square_lk">[b] square</a></li>
                <li><a href="#history" class="history_lk">[b] history</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

this is my CSS:

```
.nav ul { 
position: absolute; margin-top: -50px; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100px; font-size: 10px !important; background-color: rgb(159,55,32); 
display: none;}
```

and finally this is my MooTools:

`var nav_divs = $$('.nav div');`

for(i=0; i

```
 nav_divs[i].onmouseover = function () {
     this.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
nav_divs[i].onmouseout = function () {
     this.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

}

All is OK in Firefox, Opera, Safari Chrome and IE8 but in IE7 when I'm over the div, ul don't display.

I've tried also with a simple jQuery function but the bug in IE7 still remains.

Thanks in advance for any suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agree, this is not a bubbling problem, it is more than likely to do with the CSS you are applying to the ul.

`top: 0` and `left: 0`, is it meant to do that on an absolute element? dunno, unless ul has to be sown at top left of the viewport (and then -50px via margin-top above would make it outside viewable area).

http://www.jsfiddle.net/uAAge/

By removing the `top:` and `left:` declarations from the css class it's fine as a relative popup (tested in ie7, ff3 and chrome). if you need to offset it now so it's better positioned around the trigger element, use marginTop and marginLeft instead.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar.
I think that your contribute is definitely near to the solution...I tested your code with IE7 and all is ok; I noticed that you simply delete "top" and "left" istructions. So I've made this change in my css but still nothing!!!
I've investigate the problem and I've found that the ul block is visible only with negative margin-top (top direction) but I need positive margin-top.
I've published my work here: http://bit.ly/dzy4ny .
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display = ''` instead of either `display = 'block'` or `display = 'none'`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a bubbling problem.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. so have you got any idea for edit and fix my code?

Comment: My conclusion is that is not a bubbling problem but some css property bug in IE7..

Answer (score 0):

You're not even using MooTools' syntax. If you would, use `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` instead of `mouseover`/`mouseout`.

```
nav_divs.each(function(el){
  el.addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
      this.getElement('ul').setStyle('display', 'block');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){...}
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer; I've used your good code but still in IE7 doesn't work...all is ok in the other browsers...

nav_divs.each(function(el){
  el.addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
      this.getElement('ul').setStyle('display', 'block');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){this.getElement('ul').setStyle('display', 'none');}
  });
});

Comment: As I just said I tried also with a simple jQuery function but nothing; definitely it's not a matter of JS...

Comment: Hmm, in that case I'm unsure what are you trying to achieve. Btw. `.nav { position: relative }` ?

Comment: Yeah, I was guessing since I have no idea what you're trying to do. Put up an example on jsfiddle.net.